# Can micromanaging issue could be brought up as an ethical issue?

Tags: management, ethics, human-resources

> “Micromanagement is a personality aberration of insecure individuals.” — *Susan K. O’Brien, organizational specialist*
>
> “One micromanager can do
> more damage to an organization than termites in the foundation of a
> house.” — *Eric Boehme, IT professional*
>
> “Micromanagement doesn’t just
> suck the life out of the workers, it sucks the life out of the
> manager, too.” — *Wally Bock, leadership expert*
>
> [Source](http://theproductivitypro.com/blog/2011/02/office-productivity-how-to-handle-a-micromanager/)

I have been micromanaged all this while and I just found out about it. After researching about this newly learned term. I have found out that many opposed this system.

Can this issue be reported to the [ethics committee](https://secure.ethicspoint.com/domain/en/default_reporter.asp) or HR personals?

Comment: micromanagement is really a *style* than a form of harassment. also, what is an "ethics society", they sound utterly terrifying. i would stay well clear of them.

Comment: Edited the link for Ethics.

Comment: i checked out that link and *i'm still terrified of the  ethics society*. Altho it would seem they're (**ironically**) just an ethically bankrupt company,  as they sell to companies the ability to say that "there is budget allocated to ethical behaviour, we don't have a culture of evil, man." Also, i think you will find that the above is the best, most accurate use of the word "ironically" you have ever read.

Comment: Why are you so afraid of ethics. They provide support and govern Unethical issue in a cooperation as a third party thus there would be no bias in the end result. Which is bad for higher rank personal, whom seem always to find a loop hole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyzing ethical issues is not HR's responsibility. Acting as the representative of the company to the employees, educating employees on company policies and enforcing them through disciplinary measures if necessary and ensuring company-wide compliance with the applicable labor laws and regulations is what HR is responsible for and what it does - or at least, is supposed to do.

Feel free to report micromanagement to the ethics society if you want to, but it's not clear to me what the ethics society can do for you or what your complaint gets you.

The perception of micromanagement is highly subjective, unless we are dealing with the special case of control freaks. I wouldn't equate close supervision at critical moments and being vigorous and careful about important detail  with micromanagement but some may resent it as exactly such.

Comment: I'm not planning to complain. i just want to know is it possible to take legal action against this kind of managers.

Comment: @Sarenya First, we don't give legal advice. We don't practice medicine without a license either. Second, if you want to take legal action, what's the charge? Third, if you are asking what legal action you can take, why are you asking as the title of your post whether micromanagement is an ethical issue?

Comment: Point noted, thus we can say that micromanagement is not an ethical issue nor a problem. I just need to sit tight and adapt my self to this issue.

Comment: @Sarenya Micromanagement is not considered an ethical or legal issue but it can legitimately be considered a problematic management style, if the result is loss of team effectiveness, the team losing sight of the big picture, being alienated from the manager and being kept inordinately busy focusing on small parts at the expense of the project as a whole. Supervision is expensive and like most resources, it must be carefully allocated.

Answer (score -1):

It is an ethical issue in the sense of the level of freedom that a company is willing to give to its employees.  Micro-management itself is a generic word.  Does it apply to 'what' or 'how'?  It could mean different things to an employee - newly joined or experienced.  If it is a newly joined employee, it could mean lot more 'handholding' (lot more of 'how' than 'what').  If it more 'experienced', it could mean just 'giving top level directions' (lot more of 'what' and little/nothing of 'how').